# XMLHTTPRequest error but only when added to main project

Tags: flutter, dart, xmlhttprequest

so I have this code:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

List getMenuDay(String day, List canteenMenu) {
  if (day == "tuesday") {
    return canteenMenu[0];
  }
  else if (day == "wednesday") {
    return canteenMenu[1];
  }
  else if (day == "thursday") {
    return canteenMenu[2];
  }
  else if (day == "friday") {
    return canteenMenu[3];
  }
  else if (day == "saturday") {
    return canteenMenu[4];
  }
  else if (day == "sunday") {
    return canteenMenu[5];
  }
  else {
    return [];
  }
}

String getDayPlate(String day, String plate, List canteenMenu) {
  List dayMenu = getMenuDay(day, canteenMenu);
  if (plate == "sopa") {
    return dayMenu[0];
  }
  else if (plate == "carne") {
    return dayMenu[1];
  }
  else if (plate == "peixe") {
    return dayMenu[2];
  }
  else if (plate == "dieta") {
    return dayMenu[3];
  }
  else if (plate == "vegetariano") {
    return dayMenu[4];
  }
  return "";
}

void main() async {
  List list = [];
  List helper = [];
  const canteenUrl = 'https://sigarra.up.pt/feup/pt/mob_eme_geral.cantinas';
  var response =  await http.get(Uri.parse(canteenUrl));
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    var data = json.decode(response.body);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) { // loop through different days
      for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) { // loop through different types of food
        var parkInfo = data[3]["ementas"][i]["pratos"][j]["descricao"];
        helper.add(parkInfo);
        //print(parkInfo);
      }
      list.add(helper);
      helper = [];
      //print("--------------");
    }
    /*
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      print(list[i]);
    }
     */
    print(getDayPlate("thursday", "carne", list));
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to read $canteenUrl');
  }
}
```

and when I just create a new project, type it into the main.dart file and run it, it works fine. But when I add it to make whole project, including other files (making the necessary changed like changing the name of the function, etc), it gives me the XMLHTTPRequest error. What could be causing that? The way I'm calling it withing the main project is as follows:

```
ElevatedButton(
   style: style,
   onPressed: () {
      CanteenInfo canteen = CanteenInfo("tuesday","sopa");
      print(canteen.getDayPlate());
   },
   child: const Text('ShowLen (WIP)'),
```

Thanks for any help you could give!

Edit 1: I do get a warning when running just the code,

```
lib/main.dart: Warning: Interpreting this as package URI, 'package:new_test/main.dart'.
```

Comment: Does this error occur only on flutter web?

Comment: well, when I run just the code, I don't need an emulator because I don't have any widgets, but with the full project I open it on the Google Chrome (Web) device an that's when the error occurs. It doesn't occur as soon as I run the app, only when I click that specific button to print the "canteen.getDayPlate()" function

Comment: You can test it in dartpad and, if you open developer tools, you immediately see that the response from the server is rejected by the browser because the server does NOT provide any CORS headers. You will not be able to use this API unless the server adds your client's origin to its CORS headers, or you host your Flutter Web application at the same server.

Comment: You need to be more clear about your problem. The first code block is for a Dart app and not for a Flutter app. I've run it and I get this message `Rancho à moda de Viseu`, no error message. But that code is not gonna work for Flutter because the structure for its projects is distinct from Dart projects.